Adverse possession toll trolling
The primary defense in an adverse possession case is the toll period. It's argued that the point where the landlord initiates the lawsuit is where the toll begins and this negates the squatters claim as it runs the same time.
However, what situations cause this to fail? For example,

Courts don't use this doctrine in the first place

The original owner actually wins the lawsuit and the toll ends, but the squatter comes back on the property and/or the owner forgot or was not aware of even one tenant on the property resulting in their toll being invalid, resulting in the squatter winning the case.


How likely are either?
The suggested dupe has a absurd one line answer. It is unacceptable.

The dupe has nothing to do with this.
